# How to close angular-strap modal from controller when calling from factory

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-strap

Well, so I have seen a lot of people struggling to close the angular-strap modal from controller. I got some of the answers, but actually they do it differently (I do not want to change the code style). I open modal using my modalFactory, and so I do not have modalInstance with me. So I am compeltely not sure, how I can close this.

With angular-bootstrap, I know I can inject uibModalInstance and call uibModalInstance.dismiss() to close the function. But how I can do similar with the angular-strap modal.

Here is my factory:

```
(function (app) {
'use strict'

app.factory('modalFactory', ['$modal', function ($modal) {

    var local = this;
    local.modalInstance = ['$scope',
        function ($scope) {
               $scope.myVar = "Some variable input ";
               $scope.closeModal = function(){
                 console.log("CLose function has been called..")
                 // How I can close this.
               }
        }];

    return {
        openMyModal: function (ip) {
            $modal({
                templateUrl: 'myModal.html',
                controller: local.modalInstance,
                size: 'lg',
                resolve: {
                    ip: function () {
                        return ip;
                    }
                }
            })
        }
    }
}])
```

})(app);

Complete plunkr is available [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/Akr7HOMGOEw4YuVEdREd?p=preview).

Comment: You could call `$hide` method on `$scope`, check [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/NypD13l42zqkk7aH3K2p?p=preview)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call `$scope.$hide()` inside you **clodeModal** method.

```
(function (app) {
    'use strict'

    app.factory('modalFactory', ['$modal', function ($modal) {

        var local = this;
        local.modalInstance = ['$scope',
            function ($scope) {
                   $scope.myVar = "Some variable input ";
                   $scope.closeModal = function(){
                     console.log("CLose function has been called..")
                     $scope.$hide();
                   }
            }];

        return {
            openMyModal: function (ip) {
                $modal({
                    templateUrl: 'myModal.html',
                    controller: local.modalInstance,
                    size: 'lg',
                    resolve: {
                        ip: function () {
                            return ip;
                        }
                    }
                })
            }
        }
    }])
})(app);
```

Update plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/2FxoBzY0vQqdrxqptm6F?p=preview

Comment: OMG, this was so simple. I have used $hide() to close modal in template but never thought this must be available in $scope. Thanks a lot for helping me out.

Comment: Sure.. SO not allowing me to accept this for next 2 mins.. i will accept it soon